# nuget local repository push does not move dll

Tags: c#, nuget

I have created a C# project on my `H:\demo` drive. And I created a nuget packege.

- nuget spec
- nuget pack app.1.0.0.nupkg
- nuget push H:\nuget_repository

And I push it to nuget repository on `H:\nuget_repository`

But now when I add this package as reference to any porject, Reference source target is set as "`H:\demo\packages\app.1.0.0\lib\net45\app.dll`"
But dll should move on my project bin directory.

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>app</id>
    <version>1.0.0.1</version>
    <title>AppDemo</title>
    <authors>ok</authors>
    <owners>ok</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>app</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>app Repository</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\app.dll" target="lib"></file>
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: is your `.nuspec` correct?

Comment: updated post with nuspec

Answer (score 1):

> But dll should move on my project bin directory

No, why?

You obtain a package from a package feed. That this feed is on your local machine in this case is irrelevant, as NuGet treats feeds as transient: it copies the package into your local cache.

From there, the package is copied to your project-local cache (`..\packages\$packageName`), and then NuGet adds references to the assemblies in that directory to your project.

Then when you build your project, the referenced assemblies are copied from the package directory to the output directory (`bin`).

Comment: I have an interface on my  demo, and I referenced package to a console application. When I add a new method on my interface, console application gives runtime error to implement new method. But this will be new version. This error should be on new package created. my problem is this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that, but it sounds like you're updating a package and not changing the version, causing a MissingMethodException because you're referencing a DLL that doesn't contain that method. In short: update your package version when you make changes, because packages are cached.

Comment: I mean I created X paroject in `C:\app` and and a nuget packege of X and push it to `c:\repository`. Then I created a client application Y . And installed package X from local repository. When I change X project code, the Y project gives runtime error that code changed. But I did not directly add reference Y. I installed packege. It sholuld  give error If I update packege. make sense?

Comment: Yes, that sounds clear. What you describe indeed shouldn't happen, as the assembly from the package, not your project output is used.